# Additional review tools?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closing-questions, reviews

I've been doing some reviewing lately, and I think two additional features in the review queue would be very helpful.

First, enable the "see vote counts" from within the review tools, normally enabled with the "established user" privilege. As of right now, when I'm reviewing questions from the review queue it doesn't appear that this is enabled. I think this is important because it gives some sense of the controversy related to a question. Although, in an ideal world, all questions that *should* be closed *would* be closed, we aren't perfect yet and it'd be nice to know whether that +0 question/answer is part of a larger discussion that would provide additional context.

Second, it'd be nice to know how many close-votes a question has from the very beginning. Normally, a user with the personal close/reopen powers can see how many close votes a question has, but this feature doesn't seem to be enabled from the Review Queue. Again, in an ideal world, it wouldn't matter how many close votes a question has, but I personally take the fourth and fifth close votes a lot more seriously than the second or third ones.

Can we make these changes if there are no strong feelings against them?

Comment: First of all, could you clarify if this is focused only on Close Vote Queue, not on all review queues? Otherwise, for the first one, did you mean enabling it for anyone inside the review, even for those who still don't have the "established user" privilege? (users with 250 rep can start reviewing First Post and Late Answer, but cannot see vote counts until 1000 rep... though there's another way to see it for everyone). Fpr the second one... and if this is about Close Vote queue, you can just click "Close" and see how many votes already casted from the close vote dialog.

Comment: For the workaround, every review item has a direct link to the post. Yes, you need more clicks, but it's already viable.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose the opposite.

A question should stand by its own merits. Lots of upvotes don't mean a question is fit for the site, it just means a lot of people like it even if it is not fit. For example, this recent question has a score of 69, has 35 answers, but is not even close to being fit:

[Eternal space battle around a planet. But why?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131941/21222)

Considering other votes feels to me like saying "hey, this question is too broad, story-based and probably based on opinions, but it has upvotes so it must be good".

For a real cold and neutral analysis of questions, which allow for judging them based solely on their merits, I would have the close vote counters removed completely from the site as a while. I think the upvotes and downvotes counter has its uses as a controversy measure, but it should not be shown in the queue since it may induce a bias on the voter.

Comment: It fit better than some questions we get here!  I also take exception with "cold neutral analysis" of questions. Part of assessing the merits of a question, apart from the wording of the question itself, actually involve looking at the answers, looking at the vote counts and looking at the comments. Assess all the evidence before making a decision.

Answer (score 1):

> it'd be nice to know how many close-votes a question has from the very beginning.

I strongly disagree. You should vote on question, not on votes it already has. If it is off topic or unclear, then it is. If it isn't, then it isn't. Vote count cannot help you decide that, it can only distract you, promote conformity over honesty in you review etc. things we wouldn't want. Only exception is diamond moderator vote - diamonds may be unwilling to use modhammer, but willing to be the 5th user to VtC. And that's the only use-case I find fair.

If your voting criteria in any queue include anything but the content of question itself, you are doing it wrong and you should stop.

Comment: Okay, so counterproposal: should we stop allowing users to see the number of close votes at all? It’s the inconsistency that bothers me mostly

Comment: @Dubukay on close review queue? Sure. On First Post queue, where vote is valid review action? Not sure...